# No puedo conectar bases de datos MySQL desde JAVA (problema con la URL)

Tags: java, mysql

no puedo realizar la conexión de MySQL desde un servidor remoto, (específicamente del servicio de hosting "https://tecnoweb.net". (Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server)
el código funciona en una base de datos Local, igualmente funciona un servidor de prueba (https://remotemysql.com/).
el codigo:

```
public class Conexion {

    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://www.emsebodega.cl:3306/emsebode_inventariobd";
    private final String usuario = "user";
    private final String password = "pw";

    public Connection getConexion() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, usuario, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Está el puerto abierto? ¿Tiene levantado el servicio de mysql?

Comment: si claro, el servicio esta funcionando, y este esta alojado en un servidor remoto hosting